# get index at 0,1,list/2,(list/2+1),2,3

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dicts and I wants to get the elements at index `0,1,list/2,(list/2+1),2,3,....

As an example i have following list of dicts.

```
test = [{'aa':0},{'ab':0},{'ba':0},{'bb':0},{'ca':0},{'cb':0},{'da':0},{'db':0},{'ea':0},{'eb':0},{'fa':0},{'fb':0}]
```

```
output: [{'aa':0},{'ab':0},{'da':0},{'db':0},{'ba':0},{'bb':0},{'ea':0},{'eb':0},{'ca':0},{'cb':0},{'fa':0},{'fb':0}]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
If is do sommeting like this.

```
[item for sublist in zip(test[:middel], test[middel:]) for item in sublist]
```

I get following output.

```
[{'aa':0},
 {'da':0},
 {'ab':0},
 {'db':0},
 {'ba':0},
 {'ea':0},
 {'bb':0},
 {'eb':0},
 {'ca':0},
 {'fa':0},
 {'cb':0},
 {'fb':0}]
```

if I split test in 2 (in the middle)

```
list1 = [{'aa': 0}, {'ab': 0}, {'ba': 0}, {'bb': 0}, {'ca': 0}, {'cb': 0}]
list2 = [{'da': 0}, {'db': 0}, {'ea': 0}, {'eb': 0}, {'fa': 0}, {'fb': 0}]
```

I wants a new list with the first 2 dicts of list1, then the 2 first of list2,
then the middle 2 of list1, then the middle 2 of list2
then the last 2 of list1, then the last 2 of list2

The real dicts does look like this

```
{'datasource': 'InfluxDB', 'fieldConfig': {'defaults': {'mappings': [], 'thresholds': {'mode': 'absolute', 'steps': [{'color': 'yellow', 'value': None}, {'color': 'green', 'value': 50}, {'color': 'red', 'value': 400}]}, 'unit': 'kwatt'}, 'overrides': []}, 'gridPos': {'h': 5, 'w': 4, 'x': 14, 'y': 14}, 'id': 104, 'options': {'colorMode': 'background', 'graphMode': 'none', 'justifyMode': 'auto', 'orientation': 'horizontal', 'reduceOptions': {'calcs': ['lastNotNull'], 'fields': '', 'values': False}, 'text': {'titleSize': 16, 'valueSize': 16}, 'textMode': 'auto'}, 'pluginVersion': '8.1.1', 'targets': [{'alias': 'Gevraagd vermogen', 'groupBy': [{'params': ['$__interval'], 'type': 'time'}, {'params': ['null'], 'type': 'fill'}], 'orderByTime': 'ASC', 'policy': 'default', 'refId': 'B', 'resultFormat': 'time_series', 'select': [[{'params': ['GV'], 'type': 'field'}, {'params': [], 'type': 'last'}, {'params': [' / 10'], 'type': 'math'}]], 'tags': []}, {'alias': 'Geleverd vermogen', 'groupBy': [{'params': ['$__interval'], 'type': 'time'}, {'params': ['null'], 'type': 'fill'}], 'orderByTime': 'ASC', 'policy': 'default', 'refId': 'A', 'resultFormat': 'time_series', 'select': [[{'params': ['Actief vermogen'], 'type': 'field'}, {'params': [], 'type': 'last'}]], 'tags': []}], 'timeFrom': None, 'timeShift': None, 'type': 'stat'}
```

Comment: I don't understand, is `test` the **input**? what is the **expected output**?

Comment: Dicts have no indexes

Comment: @DeepSpace this is a **list** of dictionaries ;)

Comment: test is input and output: is expected output

Comment: So you want to relocate the back half of the list after index 1? What happens after index 3? What size limitations are there on the list? Why do you need dictionaries to represent this?

Comment: i edited the question. Is it now more clear?

Comment: @TheProgrammer thanks for clarifying, [here is an attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70609527/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example is a bit complex and can be simplified to:

Change this input:

```
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

into this output:

```
o = [0, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 4, 5, 10, 11]
```

using the algorithm you describe.

This can be achieved easily using iterators:

```
def reorder(l, by=2):
    half = len(l)//2
    a, b = iter(l[:half]), iter(l[half:])
    out = []
    for i in range(len(l)//(2*by)):
        for i in range(by):
            out.append(next(a))
        for i in range(by):
            out.append(next(b))
    return out
    
o = reorder(i)
```

on the provided data:

```
>>> reorder(test)
[{'aa': 0},
 {'ab': 0},
 {'da': 0},
 {'db': 0},
 {'ba': 0},
 {'bb': 0},
 {'ea': 0},
 {'eb': 0},
 {'ca': 0},
 {'cb': 0},
 {'fa': 0},
 {'fb': 0}]
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks @mozway

Comment: I think it doesn't work with lists of an odd lenght.

Comment: @TheProgrammer indeed, your algorithm requires a multiple of `by*2`, what would be the output for an input of non-multiple length?

Comment: if the list is non-multiple the 2 values in the middle gets seperated.

Comment: Can you provide the exact input/output for a linear integer range as in my answer? you have actually 4 cases to handle for lenghts 12 (the one already solved), 13, 14, 15 ;)

Comment: Is this the best way to handel odd list lenghts?

Comment: I don't know the output you expect. Can you give the expected output for those 3 cases `i2 = list(range(13)) ; i3 = list(range(14)) ; i4 = list(range(15))`?

Comment: The list are always even. when len(list)/2 is odd than there is a problem
Expected output:
i2 = list(range(14))
i2 [0, 1, 8, 9, 2, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 12, 13,6 ,7]
i3 = list(range(16))
i3 [0, 1, 8, 9, 2, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 12, 13,6 ,7, 14, 15]
i4 = list(range(18))
i4 [0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 12, 13, 4, 5, 14, 15,6 ,7, 16, 17,8,9]

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_list = []
l_2 = int(len(test) / 2)
for one, two, mid_one, mid_two in zip(test[:l_2:2], test[1:l_2:2], test[l_2::2], test[1 + l_2 :: 2]):
    new_list.append(one)
    new_list.append(two)
    new_list.append(mid_one)
    new_list.append(mid_two)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a solution that avoids a for loop:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
pair = list(pairwise(inputs)) # -> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), ...]
del pair[1::2] # remove [(2, 3), (4, 5), ...]
first, second = pair[:len(pair)//2], pair[len(pair)//2:] # first = [(1, 2), (3, 4)], second = [(5, 6), (7, 8)]

def merge_tuple(x):
    return x[0] + x[1]

output = list(map(merge_tuple, zip(first, second))) # -> [(1, 2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 7, 8)]
output = output[0] + output[1]
```

If your python version is too old to have pairwise you can use [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)